# Problem: Anchored controls are overlapping

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say we have two panels, listboxes, etc... on the same "row" .. by "row" I mean their TOP property is the same so they are horizontally at the same level.
now If I set the anchor property of these two controls to top-left-right and I drag the right side of the form, the contorl that is at left hand side will overlap the control at the right hand side and it gets so ugly. 
How can I both achieve this resizing goal and also NOT to use the new things we have in C# like TableLayout .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get this out of the Anchor property, a TLP is an obvious solution.  If you don't want to use that either then implement the form's Resize event and modify the controls Location and Size properties yourself.